# Dropbox Sync API "Account not getting linked"

Tags: android, api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am following [this Dropbox Tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android#linking-accounts) to start and setup my "Hello dropbox sync app".
In that am getting errors although i am going to steps given in the tutorial.
Permissions,App KEY,APP SECRET ,etc all are at their places still am not getting where i'm going wrong.
please help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance

here is my Manifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bguru.mydropboxdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bguru.mydropboxdemo.MyDropboxDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="db-MY_APP_KEY" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
</application>
```

java code :

```
public class MyDropboxDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    Button btnLinkToDropbox;
    DbxAccountManager dropBoxAcMngr;
    static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DROPBOX = 444;
    static final String APP_KEY = "MY_APP_KEY";
    static final String APP_SECRET = "MY_APP_SECRET";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_dropbox_demo);
    dropBoxAcMngr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(this, APP_KEY , APP_SECRET);

    btnLinkToDropbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkDropboxAC);
    btnLinkToDropbox.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    dropBoxAcMngr.startLink(getParent(), REQUEST_LINK_TO_DROPBOX);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DROPBOX)
    {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            btnLinkToDropbox.setText("Successfully Linked To Your Dropbox Account");
            btnLinkToDropbox.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Account Linked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            btnLinkToDropbox.setText("Failed to Link Your Dropbox Account\nTry Again?");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Linking failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

logcat shows :

```
    04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initNativeLib(CoreAccountManager.java:109)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.<init>(CoreAccountManager.java:89)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:112)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:99)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.bguru.mydropboxdemo.MyDropboxDemoActivity.onCreate(MyDropboxDemoActivity.java:27)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1662)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1726)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:949)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<init>(NativeLib.java:33)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<clinit>(NativeLib.java:11)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     ... 18 more
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load DropboxSync: findLibrary returned null
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.<clinit>(NativeHttp.java:364)
04-17 11:08:52.740: E/AndroidRuntime(4492):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: maybe post your logcat?

Comment: I don't know how dropBox is working.. but is there any jar file you need to add to your project?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610906/error-in-dropboxsync-findlibrary-returned-null

Comment: thanks @Elior ...even i did the same mistake , had not added tht armeabi libraries...adding them solved my problem...thanks again.

Comment: You're Welcome.. 
You can edit this as solved :) so people will know you found a solution..

Comment: please can you tell me how to add the armeabi libraries in eclipse with android