# Conflict dropbox sync api with another native library in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, dropbox-api

My app use `tess-two` (https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library which uses native api. When I use separate `tess-two` or `dropbox sync api`, there is nothing happen. But my app need to use both libraries, and when I add two libraries at the same time, I got the exception with `dropbox sync api` like this:

```
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initNativeLib(CoreAccountManager.java:155)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.<init>(CoreAccountManager.java:126)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:149)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:115)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.appiphany.roboscanner.utils.Config.getDropboxAccountManager(Config.java:19)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.appiphany.roboscanner.DocumentListFragment.onAttach(DocumentListFragment.java:110)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:883)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.appiphany.roboscanner.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:28)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<init>(NativeLib.java:33)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.<clinit>(NativeLib.java:11)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    ... 26 more
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load DropboxSync: findLibrary returned null
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
 11-20 16:18:30.440: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeHttp.<clinit>(NativeHttp.java:446)
```

I'm sure that I have copied all .so and jar library files of dropbox sync api into my libs folder. And I also refer this link [Error in dropboxSync: findlibrary returned null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610906/error-in-dropboxsync-findlibrary-returned-null), but it doesn't work. 
 Is there any idea?

Update: my Android.mk of tess-two look like this ( I don't change anything from github source because I think two libraries don't reference each other):

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 TESSERACT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
 LEPTONICA_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src

 # Just build the Android.mk files in the subdirs
 include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

Comment: How does your Android.mk look like?

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't change anything from github source because I think two libraries don't reference each other. Is there any problem?

Comment: I suspect something's going wrong with the build process in the presence of the two libraries. Can you please submit a support ticket using the "API Support" link on dropbox.com/developers? Please include some additional information:

- The version of the Sync SDK you're using

- The Android version and device where you're seeing the problem

- The name or app ID of your app

- A listing/screenshot of what's in the libs/ folder of your project after it's built.

- A listing of what's inside the generated APK file. It's a zip-file, so you can just change the extension and open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by copying libDropboxSync.so from armeabi to armeabi-v7a folder but I don't know how it can work. 
More detail in [my own question](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=108239#post-577561) from dropbox 4rum