# W/ActivityThread:ClassLoader.loadClass:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have recently updated my Android Studio and I ran into this problem when trying to use an already working app that makes REST calls to my backend.

```
W/ActivityThread﹕ ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
```

I am not sure what this means or where I should make the Thread.setContextClassLoader() call. Could it had been the Android Studio update?

Comment: Is there anything else in LogCat indicating possible cause for this crash? I.e in this SO question it seems failing loadLibrary call leads to the same error message line ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417027/dropbox-sync-api-unsatisfied-link-error

Comment: Nope no other message. Thats all I get.