# Android Dropbox Sync API - findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.6, gradle, and dropbox sync 3.0.2

This code:
`DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);`

is throwing this error:
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load DropboxSync from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.winslow.healthkit-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/io.winslow.healthkit-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null`

I've tried solving it according to this stack overflow ([Dropbox Sync API - Unsatisfied Link Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417027/dropbox-sync-api-unsatisfied-link-error)) but that hasn't solved the issue.

Looking for any suggestions or leads on how to possibly fix this. Thanks.

**Update:** Look at Greg's comment to fix android studio.

Comment: The standard instructions for the Dropbox Sync SDK for Android are for using Eclipse, but we have a blog post about using Android Studio here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/57/using-the-sync-api-with-android-studio Give those instructions a try if you haven't already and let us know if it doesn't help.

Comment: @Greg awesome! I had seen that blog post but misunderstood the native libs part. You've been a big help thank you! You've made my day much better! Just an FYI gradle gives a warning that `Compile` in `tasks.withType(Compile)` is deprecated but currently works fine!