# Dropbox sync api with android studio: Couldn't load DropboxSync from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android, android-studio, dropbox-api

I tried adding armeabi-v7 like suggested in [Dropbox Sync API - Unsatisfied Link Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417027/dropbox-sync-api-unsatisfied-link-error). I also tried adding Gradle command as suggested [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/57/using-the-sync-api-with-android-studio).

Still get the same message.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=122924 ]

Comment: ok! got the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26852475/4231147